# Truncate table takes too long waiting db file async i/o submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, truncate

I've got Oracle 12c data warehouse database on oracle Linux 7.3, and there's job that truncating one table. Table has size of 5GB
And always truncate takes about hour with waiting for "db file async i/o submit".
Filesystemio and disk_asynch_io are set to asynch already.

What can I do here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like it is probably waiting for outstanding async transactions to be written to disk before it does the truncate. Truncate just moves the high water mark of the table in the data file, but it would have to wait for pending transactions to commit and be written to know where the high water mark is starting from and where it should be moved to. The truncate itself should be instantaneous; I think you're waiting for everything that happened *before* the truncate.

Comment: @pmdba, thank you for your reply. Do you know how to speed up asynch submit if it possible?

Comment: The speed is mostly dependent on your storage hardware. There likely isn't a lot you can do at the database level other than throttle your application transactions to reduce the number of submissions waiting at any given time. Not sure that really helps your situation and would probably significantly affect application performance. Sounds like you need faster storage.

Comment: @pmdba thanks a lot!